# Is there a way to automatically start a DMS on create task method Boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-dms

When creating a DMS replication task using AWS Console we have this option:

[image]

which starts it automatically after the creating task is done, is there a way to configure that using boto3 [`create_replication_task`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Client.start_replication_task) method?

Comment: My guess would be that [create_event_subscription](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Client.create_event_subscription) could be used for that. Have you looked at it?